# PyInstaller modules and DLL missing

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller, py2exe

My error message doesn't say much,

> File "C:...\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 714, in load_module  module = loader.load_module(fullname) 
>   importError: dll load failed: the specified module could not be found.

So i tried to find some solutions(stackoverflow, google...), and then I downloaded Dependency Walker, and I found many dlls with (red or orange?) boxes, then I supposed it was the missing DLLs, then I copied from system32 all of those red marked DLLs to /python35/Scripts/dist/ and nothing diffent happened.

[image]

I also tried py2exe, but i just can't download pyobjc from pip or easy-install. Because I think it is not for windows, so I have no ideia...

py2exe error message:

> 5 missing Modules   ------------------ ? AppKit
>   imported from keyboard._darwinkeyboard ? Quartz
>   imported from keyboard._darwinkeyboard ? Queue
>   imported from keyboard, keyboard._generic, keyboard._nixcommon ?
>   readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb ?
>   tkinter                             imported from **SCRIPT**

I am using Windows, python35.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently similar problem (also missing dlls), the problem with python to exe "compilers" seems to be that they aren't always able to find all the packages themselves. I'd advice you to try another, e.g. cx_freeze [This guy explains it clearly](https://youtu.be/HosXxXE24hA).The point is you create initializing script (like in video) in which you specify **which modules to include**.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try it as soon as possible!!

Comment: Thanks dude, It was really painful, but at least cx_freeze gives better warnings or error messages! I got it, but it was really painful!! haha thanks!!

Comment: Haha, I'm glad I could help